# How can I set up logging with latest Tor Browser?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, mac, windows, linux, log

The current version of the Tor Browser Bundle doesn't contain Vidalia. Therefore it is quite hard to have a look in the log file and to find relevant messages. What is the best way to set up logging using version 3.5 or later of Tor Browser Bundle? How can I open the log file? How can this be done in GNU/Linux, Windows and Mac OS X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Tor FAQ](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#Logs) you should be able to find the log files in the following paths:

- On OS X, Debian, Ubuntu, Red Hat, etc.: `/var/log/tor`
- Windows: no default log files on Windows. If you enable logging in `torrc` file, logs would appear in `\username\Application Data\tor\log\` or `\Application Data\tor\log\`

You can always [set up custom logging](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#Logs) by editing you `torrc` file.

For example, add the following line to your `torrc` file to log at the [`debug` level](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#LogLevel):

> Log debug file /path/to/log/tor_debug.log

You can then open/inspect Tor logs using text editors, specialized log viewers (e.g. [Gnome System Log Viewer](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-system-log)) or command lines tools such as `grep` and `tail`.

Comment: This FAQ entry talks about a daemon. I'd like to have an example which fits more into to TBB. My goal is to have a reference Q&A to which I can point users later. ;)

Comment: The logs you would see in Vidalia (e.g. Bootstrapping %X...) were indeed coming from Tor daemon. Do you want to have something like NSPR logging from Tor Browser?